# Using POST method on an embedded website

Tags: html, post

How, if possible, would I send a value using the POST method to an embedded webpage? For example,

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http://example.com" method="post">
        <input name="uname">
        <input name="pword" type="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

<!-- I want to send "uname" and "pword" to this object/embedded website below-->

<object data="http://example.com" height="400" width="600">
    <embed src="http://example.com" height="400" width="600">
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can it be an iframe instead of an object?

Comment: @Musa I don't know how to use iframes (I'm a bit of a newbie at HTML), but it would work if it has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an iframe and set the form's target attribute to the iframe's name attribute.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http://example.com" method="post" target="target_frame">
        <input name="uname">
        <input name="pword" type="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

<!-- I want to send "uname" and "pword" to this object/embedded website below-->

<iframe name="target_frame"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```